# Wrong pdf with DOMPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, dompdf

I'm trying to generate a .pdf file. but i can't concatenate my text:
This is my code:

```
<?php 
include('conexion.php');
$con = conexion();
$sql="select * from [my table] where [condition] ";
$res=mysql_query($sql,$con);

$concli=conexion();
$sqlcli="select *  from [my table] where [condition]";

$rescli=mysql_query($sqlcli,$concli);
$datocli=mysql_fetch_array($rescli);
$codigoHTML='
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>PDF</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<div align="left">
<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="186" height="88" alt="playss.net"/> </div><br/>
<hr />
<div >
<pre>
Nombre del cliente:  <input type="text" value="'; //HERE I'M TRYING TO CONCATENATE
echo $datocli['nomempresacli'];
$codigoHTML='
">
Nombre del Vendedor  <input type="text" value="">
Proyecto:            <input type="text" >
Fecha:               <input type="text" >
</pre>
<table width="95%" height="100%" border="1">
<tr height="40">
<td>#</td>
<td >Id Producto</td>
<td >Parte</td>
<td >Descripci&oacute;n</td>
<td >Cantidad</td>
<td >Precio</td>
<td >Subtotal</td>
<td >Descuento</td>
<td >total</td>
</tr>';
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$contador=1;

while ($dato=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$codigoHTML.='
      <tr>
        <td>'.$contador.'</td>
        <td>'.$dato['idproducto'].'</td>
        <td>'.$dato['parte'].'</td>
        <td>'.$dato['descripcion'].'</td>
        <td>'.$dato['cantidad'].'</td>
        <td>'.$dato['precio'].'</td>
        <td>'.$dato['subtotal'].'</td>
        <td>'.$dato['descuento'].'</td>
        <td>'.$dato['total'].'</td>
      </tr>';
      $contador++;
      } 
$codigoHTML.='
    </table>
</div>
<pre>
<div align="right">
Total Final:  <input type="text" >
</div>
</pre>
<br/>
<hr/>


</form>

</body>
</html>
';

$codigoHTML=utf8_decode($codigoHTML);
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($codigoHTML);

ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("cotizacion.pdf");
?>
```

[image: img]

I think the mistake i have is in the next lines:

```
Nombre del cliente:  <input type="text" value="'; //HERE I'M TRYING TO CONCATENATE
echo $datocli['nomempresacli'];
$codigoHTML='
">
```

I have to add more lines like this one, but if it does not work in one, it will not work in more

could somebody help me?

Comment: **WARNING**: 
`mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: @tadman I 'll take it into account , thanks.

Comment: You are not appending/concatenating anything. You are just re-assigning the `$codigoHTML` variable. To append/concatenate, assign using the `.=` operator like `$codigoHTML.="some text";`. Also, echo'ing out a variable sends that to the user as output, it doesn't append to a string. You can append using the `.=` with a variable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is you are no contactenating the final HTML result properly:

Use as this:

```
Nombre del cliente:  <input type="text" value="'; //HERE I'M TRYING TO CONCATENATE
$codigoHTML.= $datocli['nomempresacli'];
$codigoHTML.= '
">
Nombre del Vendedor  <input type="text" value="">
Proyecto:            <input
```